# Translation TT file from Vb.net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have the following code in VB.NET

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="VB" #>
<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#

Dim inputFile= Path.ChangeExtension(Host.TemplateFile, "resx")
Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load(Host.ResolvePath(inputFile))
Dim dataElements = xml.Elements().Where(Function(x) x.Name = "data")
Dim resourceTypeName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile)
#>

' This file is autogenerated
Public Class <#= resourceTypeName #>Constants

<# For Each d as XElement in dataElements #>
 Public Const <#= d.@name #> As String = "<#= d.@name #>"
<# Next #>

End Class
```

I made a rewrite to C#. But i forgot something i think.
Because i get an error ( ErrorGeneratingOutput )

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#
dynamic inputFile = Path.ChangeExtension(Host.TemplateFile, "resx");
XElement xml = XElement.Load(Host.ResolvePath(inputFile));
dynamic dataElements = xml.Elements().Where(x => x.Name == "data");
dynamic resourceTypeName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile);
#>

'This file is autogenerated

public class <# resourceTypeName #>Contstants
{
foreach (XElement d in dataElements) {
    public Const String  <#= d.@name #> = "<#= d.@name #>";
}
}
```

Somebody who can help me?

**Update**

I get some error on line 21 , this is the line

```
public class <# resourceTypeName #>Contstants
```

He give as error Compiling transformation: ; expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `'This file is autogenerated` to `//This file is autogenerated`.

Additionally, the foreach in the first version is a TT foreach not a VB one. Try this:

```
<# foreach (XElement d in dataElements) {#>
    public const string  <#= d.@name #> = "<#= d.@name #>";
<# } #>
```